# Exporting GCP Compute Engine instance fails: Quota 'SSD_TOTAL_GB' exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, export, google-cloud-storage

I'm following instruction on: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image

When running:

```
gcloud compute images export --destination-uri gs://my-bucket/my-image.tar.gz \
--image my-image --project my-project
```

The export will fail on following error message:

```
[Daisy] Errors in one or more workflows:
image-export: step "image-export-export-disk" run error: step "setup-disks" run error: googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'SSD_TOTAL_GB' exceeded. Limit: 100.0 in region us-central1., quotaExceeded
```

This is 8GB disk image, so it's not very big.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this error:

> image-export: step "image-export-export-disk" run error: step "setup-disks" run error: googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'SSD_TOTAL_GB' exceeded. Limit: 100.0 in region us-central1., quotaExceeded

It seems like while you are still in the Free Trial Account. Normally, while in Free Trial you are not entitled to quota changes. To be entitled for quota increases, you will need to upgrade your account. Instructions are available on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/free-trial-quotas) and More specifically in this [URL](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#upgrading-billing)

Comment: So why does the OP get the quota limit of 100GB even though he/she does not seem to exceed it? That is what the OP asks.